# Unexpected behavior of the `alias_method` or `alias` keyword when usage with an inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance, alias

I'm getting this wired behavior when trying to use alias_method with an inheritance:

```
class First
  def calculate
    puts value
  end
end

class Second < First
  def result
    'Second:result'
  end
  alias_method :value, :result
end

class Third < Second
  def result
    'Third:result'
  end
end

Third.new.calculate
# => Second:result
```

- Expected: "'Third:result'"
- Actual: "Second:result"

so, we can resolve it in this way:

```
class First
  def calculate
    puts value
  end
end

class Second < First
  def result
    'Second:result'
  end

  def value
    result
  end
end

class Third < Second
  def result
    'Third:result'
  end
end

Third.new.calculate
# => Third:result
```

or this way:

```
class First
  def calculate
    puts value
  end
end

class Second < First
  def result
    'Second:result'
  end
  alias_method :value, :result
end

class Third < Second
  def result
    'Third:result'
  end
  alias_method :value, :result
end

Third.new.calculate
# => Third:result
```

but the question is: why it is not working as *expected* in the first case?

The inheritance is kind of "bad pattern", but it can be valuable when usage Policy inheritance with DRY in Rails, for example

Comment: That's exactly how I would expect it to work.  Think of alias_method as simply syntax sugar for retyping the aliased method (ok not quite b/c Ruby has open classes but for inheritance purposes).  If it didn't work this way then you would always have to type out identical methods that you wanted to allow (independent) overrides for in subclasses.  I read this question literally because it made me worry it *didn't* work the way you found unexpected.

Comment: @PeterGerdes  Yes Peter, it's unexpected from my point of view only, probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Turns out that alias_method creates an alias that references the original method rather than the overwritten one.`

The source with more details: https://theinternate.com/2014/02/14/inheritable-aliases-in-ruby.html

---

note:

It was confused for me, so that's why I decided to share it, I hope it's would be helpful for somebody, to avoid possible confusion.

---

note_2:

the same with the `alias` keyword:

```
class First
  def calculate
    puts value
  end
end

class Second < First
  def result
    'Second:result'
  end
  alias value result
end

class Third < Second
  def result
    'Third:result'
  end
end

Third.new.calculate
# => Second:result
```

can be resolved in the same way:

```
class First
  def calculate
    puts value
  end
end

class Second < First
  def result
    'Second:result'
  end
  alias value result
end

class Third < Second
  def result
    'Third:result'
  end
  alias value result
end

Third.new.calculate
# => Third:result
```

Comment: Maybe you should then have used `alias` and not `alias_method`?

Comment: @user1934428 I've updated the answer. As you can see, the same for `alias` method

Comment: Ah, you are right. In your case, the [difference between `alias` and `alias_method`](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/01/08/alias-vs-alias-method.html) does not show up. BTW, you should not call `alias` a _method_. `alias_method` is a method, but `alias` is a keyword.

Comment: @user1934428 yeah, your right, it's keyword, it was typo, I've edited the answer, thanks!